# Struggling with validation (presence, then digit, then range). I think i need to be using the try and except then the if statement

Tags: python

```
flag=False
while flag==False:
    try:
        HoursWorked=input("Please enter the employee's hours worked")
        if len(HoursWorked)!=0:
            if HoursWorked.isdigit():
                if HoursWorked>=0 and HoursWorked<=40:
                    flag=True                           
                else:
                    print(" invalid, the range accepted is from digits 0-40 entered only")
            else:
                print("invalid, only digits (whole numbers) may be entered")

    except:
        print("Hours Worked is", HoursWorked)
```

Comment: What did the code do differently than expected?

Comment: @Lina You gave no explanation as to what's wrong with your code. But I could assume that it's because your'e comparing the input to `0` and only then checking if it is a digit. Indeed a try except could be useful here.

Comment: @Nexaspx she's checking for the length and not the value as such.

Comment: @RaghulRaj You're right. Thanks.

Comment: The field "Title" is for a **short** and **relevant** description only. The longer explanation and what you tried go in the much larger field "Body" underneath. Read the [Tour], [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting), and [How do I write a good title?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title). You can **[edit]** your post to put it into better shape.

Answer (score 0):

I'd rewrite the code as such:

```
while True:
    try:
        hours_worked = int(input('Please enter the employee\'s hours worked\n'))
        if hours_worked >= 0 and hours_worked <= 40:
            print('Hours Worked is {0}'.format(hours_worked))
            break
        else:
            print('invalid, the range accepted is from digits 0-40 entered only')
    except ValueError as e:    
       print('invalid input, not a valid integer.')
```

There's no need to keep a flag like `flag`, because when you read a valid input you could just `break` out of the loop.

Also, I used the `int()` method and let it do the conversions and throw exceptions when needed.

Notice The `except` clause contains the part of the code that is caused by an exception! The "valid" part of your code should stay in the `try` clause.